# Is there an API or other data source for FlightRadar24 aircraft flight path?

Tags: api, maps

I would like to know if there is an API that gives freely the flight paths of all aircraft currently flying or that had flight some days ago over the world. It could be in any projection and any format. I imagine that it would be most likely a table with each row being an aircraft/flight and the correspondent geopath in one column.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around for the same topic.

The terms and conditions for getting data from Flightradar24 are shown there
https://www.flightradar24.com/terms-and-conditions
... they talk only about getting data after a business contract on the kind of data (e.g. flights with a specific filtering) and on the format (JSON, CSV, ?). With the contract one may download the data, maybe via an API.

My conclusion: Flightradar24 does not share its full set of data, only a limited set with payment.

Searching for "Flightradar24 API" you will find some sites offering Flightradar24 data via their own API primarily requiring payment, a few for free at a very low level.

You will also find some software projects for accessing and processing data from the Flightradar24 sites with a focus on Python. But these software packages build on tracking the access of the Flightradar24 site from a mobile app or the desktop browser. Result: a few accesses of an endpoint may work then comes the stop sign: Flightradar requires an authenticated access.